# Seeking pixelated font

Tags: software-rec, fonts, pixels

I'm seeking a font graphic (images, not TTF format or something that needs to be useable by a computer) that fits in 9 by 9 pixels.

Can anyone recommend a free source, or a simple technique for making one? I think that this ought to be do-able by a single line with GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick, but have not been able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the internet for these two fonts, you should find some interesting things:

- DOS font
- Commodore 64 font
- C64 font

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I read "not TTF" as "not TIFF."  What you might need to search for is "bitmap fonts."  But, the good news is that ImageMagick can use TTF (TrueType fonts).